# Graphics2D is returning "NULL" always

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

graphics2D is returning "NULL" always in below code. Due to that putPixel() method is not being called. I am calling PictureBox from form design.

```
public class PictureBox extends JPanel {

Graphics2D graphics2D;
static BufferedImage image;
int imageSize = 300;

public PictureBox(){
    setDoubleBuffered(false);
    this.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("ComboBox.border"));
    this.repaint();     
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);
        if(image == null){  
            image = new BufferedImage(imageSize, imageSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.createGraphics();
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            clear(); 
        }
          Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
          g2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
     repaint(); 
}

public final void putPixel(int x, int y, Color color) {
    if(graphics2D != null){
    graphics2D.setColor(color);
    graphics2D.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
    repaint();
    }
}
public void clear() {
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, imageSize,imageSize);
    repaint();
}
```

}

putPixel method is being called from main where i have (x,y) coordinate stored in Point2D array.

Comment: Why do you call `repaint` in `paintComponent`?

Comment: Where are `image`, `graphics2D` and `imageSize` defined?

Comment: you have called repaint()  in clear and paintComponent methods this is wrong. As repaint itself will call paintComponent

Comment: @JonnyHenly I have initialized image, graphics2D and imageSize inside PictureBox class only. Haven't Shown that here in my code.

Comment: could you upload the code for initialising the above so that we could understand a bit better

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 4) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: since you have called putPixel from outside the class and you have not initialised the `graphics2D` and `image` in the constructor it may be that when you all calling `putPixel` method the class may not have been displayed. So you are getting graphics2D to be null as it initialises only when the `paintComponent` is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have called `putPixel` from outside the class and you have not initialised the `graphics2D` and `image` in the constructor it may be that when you all calling `putPixel` method the class may not have been displayed. So you are getting `graphics2D` to be `null` as it initialises only when the paintComponent is called and it is called when this class gets displayed.

The solution could be that you shift the initialisation code for the `image` and `graphics2D` to the constructor so that you do not encounter `null` while calling `putPixel`.

**NOTE**

You have indiscriminately called the method `repaint()`. You should keep in mind that `repaint()` calls `paint()` method which in turn calls `paintComponent()` method. So if you call `repaint()` inside `paintComponent()` method, you run into the risk of creating an infinite loop. Here you have called it twice once in `paintComponent` and again in `clear` method which is called by `paintComponent`.